# How to link a C++ static library with XCode which is dependent on standard library?

Tags: c++, xcode4.5, static-libraries

I have cross compiled the exiv2 library for iOS SDK 6.0.

I confirmed using lipo -i that indeed i386(simulator) and arm7 code is present in the library.

The header files (.hpp) of exiv2 uses std. XCode is unable to find the C++ standard library.

Here is my setup:

I have one XCode project which targets iOS SDK 6.0.

Inside it, there is a folder called exiv2 and it contains a header and lib folder. The exiv2 header and the .a library are in those folders.

When I compile, I get an error that in (one given file)

`#include <string>` : no such file or directory

Any ideas on how to link the C++ std under such a setup in XCode?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `version.hpp` is not part of the C++ standard library.

Comment: Question edited please have a look again.

Comment: Okay, `<string>` is part of the C++ standard library. `<g>` I don't know details of how to set up C++ from XCode; it's always just worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Project Setting, select "Build Phases" and then "Link Binary with Libraries".
For standard C++ library, you can add (+) either "libc++.tbd" or "libstdc++.tbd"